# get value from location.href="javascript:someFunction()"?

Tags: javascript

Is is possible to get the value returned by a function, by triggering that function with `location.href='javascript:someFunction()`?

```
/* in some script */

function someFunction(action) {
   console.log('triggered');
   return 'Received';
}

/* in another script and another level */
var returned = location.href='javascript:someFunction()';

// Is it possible to get the returned value this way?
```

I know there are other solutions and possibilities, but I'm looking for a simple answer, is it possible to receive the returned values like that or not, and if yes, how?

I appreciate your kind replies.

**EDIT:**

Top level page:

```
function someFunction() {
   var collectionEvent = new CustomEvent("PageEvent", {detail: {data:lotsOfData}});
   window.dispatchEvent(collectionEvent);
}
```

Sandbox:

```
var data;
window.addEventListener("PageEvent", function(event) {
    data = event.detail.lotsOfData;
}, false);
```

So far so good, now I can trigger:

```
window.href = "javascript:someFunction()";
setTimeOut(function() {
   doTheMainFunction(data);
}, 2000);
```

That's the work around I don't like, because I don't know how much time does someFunction take to get the data from the main window object and pass to the sandbox, so I couldn't make a promise.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use eval, but it is not recommended: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Use it like this: console.log(eval(returned))

Comment: but then i lose the page contents, the page dom is removed and `Received` is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, then you can store assigning the result of the function into a variable:

```
/* in some script */

function someFunction(action) {
   console.log('triggered');
   return 'Received';
}

/* in another script and another level */
var returned = `location.href='${someFunction()}'`;

// Is it possible to get the returned value this way?
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, this didn't work, `someFunction` is in another level, and is undefined in the page that is calling it,  `location.href='${someFunction()}'` returned an error Calling undefined function.

Comment: @tinyCoder what do you mean by "another level"? Are you using nested pages via iframes?

Comment: Please check my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406953/get-value-from-location-href-javascriptsomefunction/56407103?noredirect=1#comment99424165_56407103

Comment: Can't you just call `window.someFunction()`?

Comment: No, I cannot call it from the sandbox, it's in a different window. Please check the question again, I have edited it with more details.

Comment: @tinyCoder thanks for the edit. I see the problem now. A way to solve it would be to create an onmessage event at both the parent and the child page and resolve the issue as a communication between parent and child. The child would send a message to the parent, which would receive it, execute the custom event and send a response at the end to the child. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmessage_sse.asp

Comment: @tinyCoder you can see more information here: https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication